# SSH connection reset on CentOS

Tags: centos, ssh

my SSH connection disconnect each time someone else is accessing the server from remote with SSH.
if I would like to connect again I'll need to the verify the SSH key all over again and the other remote connection will disconnect.
any idea what causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the server logs? It should be logging something. You can increase the level of logging by using `LogLevel DEBUG` in your `sshd_config`.

Check if the `MaxSessions` parameter is set on your `sshd_config`.

Are you starting the `sshd` daemon with the usual init script or directly through some invocation of the `sshd` command?

Comment: I used the default settings. I don't understand why I need to verrify the ssh key everytime I access the server

Comment: If you need to verify the SSH key every time it sounds like a local problem as this should be saved locally and checked each time you connect to see if it has changed. If it is actually changing each time then that's something else to look into, you need to clarify if it's changing or it is just not being saved locally.

Comment: Please clarify @Elad, did you mean the public key (as in typing your passphrase again) or the host key (is it saying something about the `known_hosts`?).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained the network layout at all, eg if there is any NAT or the 2 remotes are from a routed segment but different hosts, etc.
Have you tried logging into the server, then from the shell ssh to itself and see if your whole connection is disconnected. If it doesn't then it's nothing to do with the account or session itself but some sort of network issue. ie some simple mistake of 2 nics with the same subnet which is flicking between the 2 or 2 remote networks happen to be the same network and routed to this machine, you know, basic funkiness which we here have no info on from the original post.

Comment: It's a real ip server with one NIC. when I disconnect and try again with putty or Secure CRT I need to accept and save the "New Hoat key" and if someone else connects I'll disconnect and vise versa